# Ошибка mysql: Incorrect key file for table

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

На Vps кончалось место, слетел mysql, я очистил от ненужных файлов, mysql заработал, но стал выдавать такую ошибку. Как быть? Проект рабочий, помогите.

```
150314 21:26:59 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_3fcb_0.MYI'; try to repair it
150314 21:26:59 [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread, /build/buildd/mysql-5.5-5.5.41/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:226
150314 21:27:10 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_3fcb_0.MYI'; try to repair it
150314 21:27:10 [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread, /build/buildd/mysql-5.5-5.5.41/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:226
150314 21:27:15 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_3fcb_0.MYI'; try to repair it
150314 21:27:15 [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread, /build/buildd/mysql-5.5-5.5.41/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:226
150314 21:27:16 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_3fcb_0.MYI'; try to repair it
150314 21:27:16 [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread, /build/buildd/mysql-5.5-5.5.41/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:226
150314 21:27:31 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_3fcb_0.MYI'; try to repair it
150314 21:27:31 [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread, /build/buildd/mysql-5.5-5.5.41/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:226
```

Comment: для начала сделайте копию файлов базы данных mysql (с остановленным  mysqld), потом `mysqlcheck -A -r`

Comment: mysqlcheck: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) when trying to connect

Comment: Показал на все ОК и не помогло

Comment: `mysqlrepair --auto-repair -Ac`

Comment: General error: 126 Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_43c1_0.MYI'; try to repair it

Answer (score 1):

Была вроде как похожая проблема. Подключаемся через консоль к MySQL. И делаем запрос ко всем таблицам на обновление Автоинкрементного значения. После этого заработало.

```
ALTER TABLE some_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Comment: @ArchDemon, если проставить всем auto increment в ноль, то наоборот вряд ли заработает

Comment: Не спрашивай, а делай. MySQL сам выставить нужный индекс на инкремент, даже если ты укажешь неправильный